# My activity goes to previous activity when firebase database change is detected

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, fragment

Thats the Fragment containing the recyclerView which leads to activity with Chat

```
public class FragmentBusinessHome extends Fragment {
/* For to do adapter */
private List<String> namesToDo;
private List<String> uids;
private List<String> servicesNames;
private AdapterToDo adapterToDo;
private RecyclerView toDoRecyclerView;

/* For checking requests adapter */
private List<String> userUids;
private List<String> serviceNames;
private List<String> userNames;
private AdapterPendingRequests adapterPendingRequests;
private RecyclerView pendingRequestsRecyclerView;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

public FragmentBusinessHome(){

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_home, container, false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    namesToDo = new ArrayList<>();
    uids = new ArrayList<>();
    servicesNames = new ArrayList<>();

    userUids = new ArrayList<>();
    serviceNames = new ArrayList<>();
    userNames = new ArrayList<>();

    toDoRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.toDoRecyclerView);
    pendingRequestsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.requestsToApproveRecyclerView);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerActive = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManagerActive.setStackFromEnd(true);
    layoutManagerActive.setReverseLayout(true);
    toDoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerActive);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerPendingRequests = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManagerPendingRequests.setStackFromEnd(true);
    layoutManagerPendingRequests.setReverseLayout(true);
    pendingRequestsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerPendingRequests);


    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DatabaseReference checkRequests = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Providers").child(uid).child("Gigs");
    checkRequests.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (ds.getValue(String.class).equals("active")) {
                    DatabaseReference getRequests = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Services").child(ds.getKey()).child(uid).child("Gigs").child("pending");
                    getRequests.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            serviceNames.clear(); userNames.clear(); userUids.clear();
                            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String userName = data.child("names").getValue(String.class);
                                String serviceName = ds.getKey();
                                String userUid = data.getKey();

                                userNames.add(userName);
                                serviceNames.add(serviceName);
                                userUids.add(userUid);

                                adapterPendingRequests = new AdapterPendingRequests(getActivity(), userUids, userNames, serviceNames, mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                adapterPendingRequests.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                pendingRequestsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPendingRequests);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    DatabaseReference getActive = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Services").child(ds.getKey()).child(uid).child("Gigs").child("active");
                    getActive.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            userUids.clear(); namesToDo.clear(); servicesNames.clear();
                            for(DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                String userUid = datas.getKey();
                                String userName = datas.child("names").getValue(String.class);
                                String serviceName = ds.getKey();

                                userUids.add(userUid);
                                namesToDo.add(userName);
                                servicesNames.add(serviceName);

                                Log.d("TAG", userUids.toString());

                                adapterToDo = new AdapterToDo(getActivity(), namesToDo, userUids, servicesNames);
                                adapterToDo.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                toDoRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterToDo);

                                if(!userUids.isEmpty()){
                                    LinearLayout toDoLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.toDoLayout);
                                    toDoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    return view;
}
}
```

Thats fragment's activity

```
private ImageButton moreBtn, chatsBtn;
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_home);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentBusinessHome()).commit();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationListener);

    moreBtn = findViewById(R.id.moreBtn);
    chatsBtn = findViewById(R.id.chatsBtn);

    moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(BusinessHomeActivity.this, moreBtn);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_toolbar_more_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.sign_out_btn:
                            mAuth.signOut();
                            new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                                    new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            Intent to_login_activity = new Intent(BusinessHomeActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(to_login_activity);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    }, 1000);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    chatsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(BusinessHomeActivity.this, "Will be available soon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                selectedFragment = new FragmentBusinessHome();
                break;
            case R.id.inbox:
                selectedFragment = new FragmentInbox();
                break;
            case R.id.profile:
                selectedFragment = new FragmentProfile();
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, selectedFragment).commit();

        return true;
    }
};
```

That's the adapter for the fragment

```
public class AdapterToDo extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterToDo.MyHolder> {
Context context;
List<String> namesToDo;
List<String> uids;
List<String> servicesNames;

public AdapterToDo(Context context, List<String> namesToDo, List<String> uids, List<String> servicesNames) {
    this.context = context;
    this.namesToDo = namesToDo;
    this.uids = uids;
    this.servicesNames = servicesNames;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterToDo.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.to_do_item, parent, false);

    return new AdapterToDo.MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterToDo.MyHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.userNames.setText(namesToDo.get(position));
    String currentUid = uids.get(position);
    String currentOppositeName = namesToDo.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent to_chat_activity = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
            to_chat_activity.putExtra("oppositeUid", currentUid);
            to_chat_activity.putExtra("oppositeNames", currentOppositeName);
            to_chat_activity.putExtra("class", getClass().getName());
            context.startActivity(to_chat_activity);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return uids.size();
}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView userNames;

    private MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userNames = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userNames);
    }
}
}
```

That is the Activity where the fragment's adapter leads to

```
private String oppositeUid, oppositeNames, className;
private TextView oppositeNamesTextView;
private Button sendBtn;
private EditText message;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<ModelChat> modelChatList;
private AdapterChat chatAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    oppositeUid = intent.getStringExtra("oppositeUid");
    oppositeNames = intent.getStringExtra("oppositeNames");
    className = intent.getStringExtra("class");
    Log.d("CLASSNAME", className);

    modelChatList = new ArrayList<>();

    oppositeNamesTextView = findViewById(R.id.oppositeNames);
    sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    message = findViewById(R.id.message);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayout.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);

    oppositeNamesTextView.setText(oppositeNames);

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String mMessage = message.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mMessage)){
                HashMap<Object, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("sender", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                hashMap.put("receiver", oppositeUid);
                hashMap.put("message", mMessage);
                hashMap.put("timestamp", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

                if(className.equals("com.example.uploy.AdapterToDo$1")){
                    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Providers").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Chats").child(oppositeUid);
                    databaseReference.push().setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            message.setText("");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "An error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(oppositeUid).child("Chats").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    databaseReference1.push().setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            message.setText("");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "An error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Providers").child(oppositeUid).child("Chats").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    databaseReference.push().setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            message.setText("");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "An error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Chats").child(oppositeUid);
                    databaseReference1.push().setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            message.setText("");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "An error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if(className.equals("com.example.uploy.AdapterToDo$1")){
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Providers").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Chats").child(oppositeUid);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                modelChatList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snapshot.getKey().equals("details")){
                        continue;
                    }
                    ModelChat modelChat = snapshot.getValue(ModelChat.class);
                    modelChatList.add(modelChat);
                    chatAdapter = new AdapterChat(ChatActivity.this, modelChatList);
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }else{
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Chats").child(oppositeUid);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                modelChatList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snapshot.getKey().equals("details")){
                        continue;
                    }
                    ModelChat modelChat = snapshot.getValue(ModelChat.class);
                    modelChatList.add(modelChat);
                    chatAdapter = new AdapterChat(ChatActivity.this, modelChatList);
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d("TAG", "PRESSED");
}
```

The **PROBLEM** is that when the fragment opens the activity (it contains messages in chat between to users, which are loaded perfectly fine) and the activity detects any change in the chats database reference it stops and loads the previous activity (where the fragment is placed). I wonder what the solution is and I would be glad if you help me.

Comment: There should be an exception, Check your logcat.

Comment: That is the only thing written: 2020-02-04 21:47:29.144 21020-21143/com.example.uploy D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=BusinessHomeActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-1065629266034046951, ga_screen_class(_sc)=BusinessHomeActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-1065629266034046950}]

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 450 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.